# Does There exist a non constant analytic function satisfying these conditions?

Tags: complex-analysis

Does There exist a non constant analytic function $f:\mathbb{C} \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ such that $f(0)=1$ and for every $z\in \mathbb{C}$ such that $|z|\geq 1$ we have $|f(z)|\leq e^{-|z|}$?

Comment: $f$ is bounded.

Answer (score 4):

Note that $$e^{-|z|} \leq 1$$ for all $z$. Hence, on $|z|\geq1$, you function is bounded by $1$, and on $|z|\leq 1$ it is bounded by a constant $M$. (Since the unit disc is compact and your function continuous.) Hence, on $\mathbb{C}$ you have $$|f(z)| \leq \sup(M,1)$$ and $f$ is constant by Liouville's theorem.

Comment: Just to add, what constant can $f$ possibly be? Actually none, so to answer the question, there are no such functions.

Comment: Yes, with the first condition, we must have $f=1$ but with the second we should have $1 \leq 1/e$ which is a contradiction.

Comment: @Soumya Sinha given $f(0)=1$ so as by C. Dubussy $f$ must be 1.

Comment: @Kernelf, see C.Dubussy's comment.